# Requests are lost occasionally, Nginx + Phusion Passenger + Rails 5

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I am running a Rails 5 app in production on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx and Phusion Passenger. Occasionally it happens, that certain request would take too long to load and end up being timed out. The same request when made again works. I have been looking for traces in the error log but found nothing over there. There were no traces of the lost request in the nginx access log either.

How can I know what exactly might be going wrong resulting in the loss of request and how can I fix this problem?

Here is what my nginx configuration looks like:

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  # Include mime types

  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  # Include Passenger conf (only contains paths to root and ruby)
  # Incude sites configurations
}
```

Comment: What is your nginx/passenger config ? Maybe this happens because passenger is/just started a new process/thread for your app, and the request was routed to this newly born app instance that is not yet fully operational. You could try setting a fixed number for your instance pool. Ie `passenger_max_pool_size`in your nginx.conf and `passenger_min_instances` in the nginx server block. `passenger-status` should give you some hints

Comment: Thanks Cyril for your reply. I don't have the max_pool_size and min_instances set yet. I'll try that now. Also attached i'm pasting my nginx configuration file here.